# Setting a static IP address while using New-AzureQuickVM

Tags: azure

I'm currently writing a powershell script that provisions a virtual machine, more testing at the moment. The code at present

```
New-AzureQuickVM -ImageName $VMImage.ImageName -Windows -Name $VMName -ServiceName $VMName -AdminUsername $adminLogin `
     -Password $adminPasswd -AffinityGroup $affinityGrp -InstanceSize $instanceSize -VNetName $virtualNetwork -SubnetNames $virtualSubnet -WaitForBoot
```

I can't see a parameter on MSDN to set the IP address of the VM. I know you can do it like this:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmname -ImageName $img –InstanceSize Small | Set-AzureSubnet –SubnetNames $sub | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress 192.168.4.7 | New-AzureVM –ServiceName $vmsvc1 –AffinityGroup "NorthEuropeAG";
```

But it seems neater to use the New-AzureQuickVM. Am I able to just pipe New-AzureQuickVM to Set-AzureStaticVNetIP similar to how New-AzureVMConfig works or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the New-AzureQuickVM  is to create the VM with absolute minimum[image] number of required fields. Like the Quick Create.

On the Other hand the New-AzureVMConfig give you all options that are necessary to have the StaticIP , as you have mentioned or something like the following.

New-AzureVMConfig -Name "testvm123" -InstanceSize "Small" -ImageName $ImageName |
    Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername $username-Password $password |
    Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames "Subnetname" |
    Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress "10.0.0.22" |
    New-AzureVM -ServiceName "somevmservicename"

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do it is by setting the IP after VM creation:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $VMName -Name $VMName | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress 192.168.4.7  | Update-AzureVM
```